# How to keep: daily backups for a week, weekly for a month, monthly for a year, and yearly after that

Tags: linux, backup, bash

I need to backup data and config files on this server, daily. I need to keep:

- daily backups for a week
- weekly backups for a month
- monthly backups for a year
- yearly backups after that

All of this accomplished via a shell script run daily from cron.

This is how the backup files should look after 10 years of running:

```
blog-20050103.tar.bz2
blog-20060102.tar.bz2
blog-20070101.tar.bz2
blog-20080107.tar.bz2
blog-20090105.tar.bz2
blog-20100104.tar.bz2
blog-20110103.tar.bz2
blog-20120102.tar.bz2
blog-20130107.tar.bz2
blog-20130902.tar.bz2
blog-20131007.tar.bz2
blog-20131104.tar.bz2
blog-20131202.tar.bz2
blog-20140106.tar.bz2
blog-20140203.tar.bz2
blog-20140303.tar.bz2
blog-20140407.tar.bz2
blog-20140505.tar.bz2
blog-20140602.tar.bz2
blog-20140707.tar.bz2
blog-20140728.tar.bz2
blog-20140804.tar.bz2
blog-20140811.tar.bz2
blog-20140816.tar.bz2
blog-20140817.tar.bz2
blog-20140818.tar.bz2
blog-20140819.tar.bz2
blog-20140820.tar.bz2
blog-20140821.tar.bz2
blog-20140822.tar.bz2
```

Comment: ...my normal suggestion would be "Use [Bacula](http://bacula.org)" (or some other backup software that can handle retention and rotation for you) :-)

Comment: this question made me write cronicle <https://github.com/Kraymer/cronicle> because the accepted answer has the obvious defect of duplicating backups into the daily/weekly/etc folders. cronicle relies on symlinks and takes care of the rotation, deleting underlying files when no folders contain symlinks pointing to it.

Comment: This is the first hit on Google for this type of backup retention which is my primary requirement. However, I'm looking for something with a GUI, unless I'm forced to use a script so I created a post in SE-software-reqs here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/linux-ubuntu-backup-with-incremental-and-smart-retention

Comment: maybe this nice tool helps someone: https://github.com/jgehrcke/timegaps

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are seriously over-engineering this. Badly.

Here's some pseudocode:

- Every day:

  - make a backup, put into `daily` directory
  - remove everything but the last 7 `daily` backups
- Every week:

  - make a backup, put into `weekly` directory
  - remove everything but the last 5 `weekly` backups
- Every month:

  - make a backup, put into `monthly` directory
  - remove everything but the last 12 `monthly` backups
- Every year:

  - make a backup, put into `yearly` directory

---

The amount of logic you have to implement is about the same, eh? KISS.

This looks easier:

```
s3cmd ls s3://backup-bucket/daily/ | \
    awk '$1 < "'$(date +%F -d '1 week ago')'" {print $4;}' | \
    xargs --no-run-if-empty s3cmd del
```

Or, by file count instead of age:

```
s3cmd ls s3://backup-bucket/daily/ | \
    awk '$1 != "DIR"' | \
    sort -r | \
    awk 'NR > 7 {print $4;}' | \
    xargs --no-run-if-empty s3cmd del
```

Comment: I actually don't have separate directories. It was written to dump files into an S3 bucket. Once everything is in one place, the total amount of logic that you need to implement is about the same, no matter how you go about it.

Comment: Evidently it isn't.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from the simple question "I need daily/weekly/monthly/yearly backups" to "you are seriously over-engineering this."

Comment: I dont like to take a full several-gb-large-vm backup several times for almost the same date, sounds like on overkill to me.

Comment: @daniel agreed; in that case you modify your backup code to only put it into the "longest" bucket.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to keep, for example, 8 daily backups and 5 weekly (every sunday) backups, it works like this:

```
for i in {0..7}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++)); done
for i in {0..4}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++)); done
echo ${!keep[@]}
```

As of today (2014-11-10), this will output:

```
20141012 20141019 20141026 20141102 20141103 20141104
20141105 20141106 20141107 20141108 20141109 20141110
```

As an exercise left for you, you just have to delete all backup files whose names do not appear in the `keep`-array.

If you want to keep 13 monthly backups (first sunday of every month) and 6 yearly backups (first sunday of every year) as well, things get a little bit more complicated:

```
for i in {0..7}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "-$i day")]++)); done
for i in {0..4}; do ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$((i+1)) week")]++)); done
for i in {0..12}; do
        DW=$(($(date +%-W)-$(date -d $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y-%m-01) +%-W)))
        for (( AY=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i month" +%Y); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
                ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
done
for i in {0..5}; do
        DW=$(date +%-W)
        for (( AY=$(($(date +%Y)-i)); AY < $(date +%Y); AY++ )); do
                ((DW+=$(date -d $AY-12-31 +%W)))
        done
        ((keep[$(date +%Y%m%d -d "sunday-$DW weeks")]++))
done
echo ${!keep[@]}
```

As of today (2014-11-10), this will output:

```
20090104 20100103 20110102 20120101 20130106 20131103
20131201 20140105 20140202 20140302 20140406 20140504
20140601 20140706 20140803 20140907 20141005 20141012
20141019 20141026 20141102 20141103 20141104 20141105
20141106 20141107 20141108 20141109 20141110
```

Same as above, just delete all backup files not found in this array.

Comment: Nice, and how do I do `rm /dir/*.* except keep[@]`?

Comment: @takeshin
If backups are named like 'auto_20200912', you can do something like this:
`for backup in "${backups[@]}"; do
    if [[ " ${!keep[*]} " != *"$(echo "$backup" | cut -d'_' -f 2"* ]]; then
        echo "Deleting: $backup"
    fi
done
`

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem. IMHO, trying to write a shell script to do it is painful, and it is much easier to write some reusable logic using a higher-level language with builtins like sets, dictionaries, etc. The general idea is to take configuration indicating how many files of each period you want to keep, and then decide for each file if it should be kept.

There is a fairly popular python-based script that looks really nice and has some easy-to-understand source. Plus being python-based instead of shell-based gives it a cross-platform advantage:
https://github.com/xolox/python-rotate-backups

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, it is normally best to delegate the task of managing backups to a backup management software.

But here is the logic in bash for deleting older backups as per you requirement

```bash
#!/bin/sh

delete() {
    echo "Deleting $1"
}

DOW=$(date +%u)

if [ $DOW -eq 1 ]; then
    DATE_DAY=$(date -d "-28 days" +"%d")
    if [ $DATE_DAY -gt 7 ]; then
        DATE=$(date -d "-28 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")
        delete $DATE
    fi

    DATE_DAY=$(date -d "-364 days" +"%d")
    DATE_MONTH=$(date -d "-364 days" +"%m")
    if [ $DATE_DAY -le 7 ] && [ $DATE_MONTH -gt 1 ]; then
        DATE=$(date -d "-364 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")
        delete $DATE
    fi
else
    DATE=$(date -d "-7 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")
    delete $DATE
fi
```

PHP Code showing which files will remain after running for 3520 days

https://ideone.com/n2ymQy

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 2005-01-03
    [1] => 2006-01-02
    [2] => 2007-01-01
    [3] => 2008-01-07
    [4] => 2009-01-05
    [5] => 2010-01-04
    [6] => 2011-01-03
    [7] => 2012-01-02
    [8] => 2013-01-07
    [9] => 2013-09-02
    [10] => 2013-10-07
    [11] => 2013-11-04
    [12] => 2013-12-02
    [13] => 2014-01-06
    [14] => 2014-02-03
    [15] => 2014-03-03
    [16] => 2014-04-07
    [17] => 2014-05-05
    [18] => 2014-06-02
    [19] => 2014-07-07
    [20] => 2014-07-28
    [21] => 2014-08-04
    [22] => 2014-08-11
    [23] => 2014-08-16
    [24] => 2014-08-17
    [25] => 2014-08-18
    [26] => 2014-08-19
    [27] => 2014-08-20
    [28] => 2014-08-21
    [29] => 2014-08-22
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem.
Basically needing space on a filesystem where daily full backups were running.

I wrote a script that just prints the rm -f commands.

Basic but good enough for me. Easy to adapt/improve.

Benefits:

- Super simple (based on find)
- easy to pipe into a file or just copy/paste the relevant output sections for interractive use
- possibly review, execute, and possibly keeping traces of the delete (cleanup) actions

Limitations:

- You need to adapt the regex if your file formats are different
- Since it's just based on a count of files, there could be a shift for a month when backups did not run or started during the month.
- **Needs some rewrites since it will delete the weekly backups on the second run. So to be used only once.** Might work if run only once per month, at the exact same day.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Build for this file format: 
# ./YYYYmmdd-HHhMM_container_name.tar.xz
# example: ./20210923-06h00_petrussewp.tar.xz

DELETE_DAILY_AFTER=30   # days
DELETE_WEEKLY_AFTER=180 # days (so keep only one monthly)

# List the backup sources to group them:
sourcename=$( ls -1 20*.tar.?z | sed -E 's/^[-h0-9]+_(.+)\.tar\.[gbx]z$/\1/' | sort | uniq )

for ctname in ${sourcename}
do
    echo "## ${ctname} backups :"
    for month in {01..12}
    do
        # Delete daily backups older than DELETE_DAILY_AFTER days.
        echo "# Obsolete daily backups for ${ctname} for the month ${month}:"
        find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "20??${month}*${ctname}*" -mtime +${DELETE_DAILY_AFTER} -printf "rm -f %p\n" | sort -n | awk 'NR % 7 != 1'
        # Delete all but the first matching backup of the month after DELETE_WEEKLY_AFTER days.
        echo "# Obsolete weekly backups for ${ctname} for the month ${month}:"
        find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "20??${month}*${ctname}*" -mtime +${DELETE_WEEKLY_AFTER} -printf "rm -f %p\n" | sort -n | awk 'NR % 7 == 1' | tail -n+2
    done
done
```

Script output example:

```
## wekan-db backups :
# Obsolete daily backups for wekan-db for the month 01:
# Obsolete weekly backups for wekan-db for the month 01:
# Obsolete daily backups for wekan-db for the month 02:
rm -f ./20210206-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210207-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210208-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210209-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210210-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210211-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210213-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210214-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210215-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210216-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210217-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210218-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210220-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210221-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210222-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210223-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210224-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210225-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210227-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210228-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
# Obsolete weekly backups for wekan-db for the month 02:
rm -f ./20210212-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210219-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
rm -f ./20210226-06h00_wekan-db.tar.xz
```